# Get innerText value from html node

Tags: c#, parsing, html-agility-pack

I am currently using the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/),

However in the following HTML-

```html
<div class="First"> Inner Text <strong><a href="url"> Text </a></strong>
<br>
Inner Text <strong><a href="url"> Text </a></strong>
<br>
<span class="Second"> Inner Text <strong><a href="url"> Text </a></strong></span>
<br>          
Inner Text <strong><a href="url"> Text </a></strong>
```

I am having difficulty extracting the `Inner Text` values as they are not nested in their own node.
I can get the `href` values, however need the corresponding text values before them, so for each link, I have the text before it.

I have tried using `Previoussibling.innerText` however results came back null.

Comment: Your `a` tag is within a `strong` tag. `elm.parentElement.previousSibling.textContent` should help, assuming `elm` is your `a` tag reference.

Comment: If you wanted all the text that shows "Inner Text" you could remove all the `<strong>` child nodes from `<div>` and get the `InnerText` of the `<div>` node.